# How to check if my entries persists in my H2 file db?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I would love to hear your insights regarding my dilemma.

Here it goes.

I want to check if my data entries from my api persists successfully in my H2 file db, but I don't have any clue on how to check persisted data via file db since I am only familiar in using NoSQL and SQL databases.

here is my application.yml configs

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  application:
    name: app1

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/src/main/resources/db/hellodb
    username: 
    password:

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

My api result in postman gives 200ok as success response but I wanna check its in my file db.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Write a select query? H2 is sql based db.

Comment: If the repository is not throwing any error then it is saved. To forcefully persist the `entity` you can use `flush()` method. Another way to verify if the `entity` exists is by `querying` for the `entity` using the `Id` you got while saving the `entity`.

Comment: btw. *url: jdbc:h2:file:~/src/main/resources/db/hellodb* doesn't look right - that's a path in what looks like your *dev* environment which shouldn't be present in a deployment

Comment: @Chaosfire does it work even if I use a File as my db and not In-memory? When I open the h2 console I couldn't see anything  like my tables or whatnot and if I also check the hellodb.text in the resource folder of my spring boot app I also couldn't see any data that persists. :(

Comment: @g00se since I only need to create a demo spring boot app that is using File as its persistence I think it will sufficed for this use case. But I appreciate the heads up. <3

Comment: @Prog_G is there no other way for me to see the data entries in my File db? the same way you can see the records in NoSql/Sql databases for example?

Comment: You do realise that *file* url (so it can't be in-memory) is off your *home* directory? So are you looking in the right place? Incidentally, I wouldn't use `~` as that's a shell thing. Maybe that didn't even resolve... `ls -l ~/src/main/resources/db/hellodb`

Comment: @g00se can you possibly expound more on your above comment? This is my first time using a File as my db for a demo requirement and I am so lost since I am only familiar with using NoSql and Sql databases..huhu

Comment: You can use H2 console just as with in-memory version. Using the url similar to the one in properties. Of course you must point to the right directory as stated in above comment.

Comment: And remember that your application must be running because even if it is file storage the database engine is embedded. Not server version.

Comment: OK. I've just got h2 and run it. You should be doing `ls -l ~/src/main/resources/db/hellodb.mv.db`

Comment: @g00se I change my yml config to url: jdbc:h2:file:ls -l ~/src/main/resources/db/hellodb.mv and got this error now in my spring boot app Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:file:ls -l ~/src/main/resources/db/hellodb.mv". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead.

Comment: *I change my yml config to url: jdbc:h2:file:ls -l ~/src/main/resources/db/hellodb.mv*. No, you're confusing your url with the commands I'm giving you to attain your *original objective* of showing your db file.Restore the original url and then run the last code I gave you *in the terminal*

Comment: Hi team. It finally works huhu  I just need to add a config in my yml to enable the h2 console now I can get in using this jdbc:h2:file:/src/main/resources/db/hellodb . Thank you everyone. You are all my hero. I love y'all sincerely from the bottom of my dev heart! <3

Comment: Good. I would use a different file url though. Something like `mkdir ~/.myappdb` then `url: jdbc:h2:file:~/.myappdb`